# Similarity solution, Heat Equation with free boundary

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

> Consider the following 1D free boundary problem: The function $x = a(t) > 0$ represents the left boundary that is free to move, and at time $t,$ we are interested in the temperature (of a liquid) in the domain $x > a(t).$  The temperature $T(x,t)$ in this domain is given by the heat equation,
>   $$ T_t = T_{xx} \text{ for } x > a(t) \text{ with } T(\infty,t) = 0.$$
>   The boundary condition at $x = a(t)$ is 
>   $$ T(a(t),t) = 1 \; \text{ and } \; S \frac{da}{dt} = - \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x = a(t)^+}$$
>   where $S$ is a dimensionless number.  Given $S > 1,$ find a similarity solution (meaning find both $T(x,t)$ and $a(t)$ using a similarity solution).  Show that the similarity solution breaks down if $S < 1.$

When there is not a free boundary, but rather the left boundary is fixed at the origin, one can find a similarity solution by letting $T(x,t) = u(\eta)$ where $\eta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}},$ and the solution ends up being the complementary error function given by the solution of the ODE, $$u''(\eta) + 2\eta u'(\eta) = 0,$$
with $u \to 0$ as $\eta \to \infty$ and $u(0) = 1 \, ( \,= T(0,t)\,).$  The similarity variable $\eta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$ seems to still be the correct similarity variable (the PDE dictates this choice), but I haven't been able to figure out how to adjust this method to account for the free boundary.

Any suggestions on how to proceed, hints, solutions? Thanks in advance!